# Bounded-waiting Mutual Exclusion with test and set

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, locking, mutual-exclusion

I am reading the famous Operating System Concepts book of (Avi Silberschatz, Peter Baer Galvin, Greg Gagne) edition 9: http://codex.cs.yale.edu/avi/os-book/OS9/

In the process synchronization chapter, there is an algorithm for "Bounded-waiting Mutual Exclusion with test_and_set" as follow:

```
do {
    waiting[i] = true;
    key = true;  // <-- Boolean variable that I do not see its utility
    while (waiting[i] && key) // <-- the value of the key variable here is always true
        key = test_and_set(&lock); // <-- it might become false here, but what is the point?
    waiting[i] = false;

    /* critical section */

    j = (i + 1) % n;
    while ((j != i) && !waiting[j]) 
        j = (j + 1) % n; 
    if (j == i) 
        lock = false; 
    else
        waiting[j] = false;

    /* remainder section */
} while (true);
```

I can't see the role of the boolean variable `key` (used in the 3rd, 4th and 5th lines of the code above), I see that we can remove it without any particular effect on the algorithm, am I right or I have missed something?

Comment: The __key__ is one of two ways used here to exit the __while loop__, it is set to false if __lock__ is false and that enable current process to execute its critical section.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could simplify the algorithm to:

```
do {
    waiting[i] = true;
    while (waiting[i] && test_and_set(&lock)) ;
    waiting[i] = false;

    /* critical section */

    j = (i + 1) % n;
    while ((j != i) && !waiting[j]) 
        j = (j + 1) % n; 
    if (j == i) 
        lock = false; 
    else
        waiting[j] = false;

    /* remainder section */
} while (true);
```

and it would be the exact same.  I guess the authors used `key` because they thought it would make the code easier to read.

As asked in the comments:

Generally, when using `test_and_set` you simply do `while(test_and_set(&lock)) ;`.  However in this case you want to ensure that the thread only waits a bounded amount of time for the lock.  This is accomplished with the `waiting` array.  At the end of the critical section when we unlock, we do not simply set `lock` to false which is how you typically unlock it.  Instead we try to find the next thread that is waiting for the lock.  By next, I mean incrementing the thread ID and then looping around when we hit `n` (the `j = (j + 1) % n;` part).  If such a thread `j` is found we set `waiting[j]` to `false` instead of `lock`.

This prevents scenarios where 2 or more threads are constantly grabbing the lock while another thread or group of threads are always waiting.  For example, say 3 threads are waiting for the same lock (threads 0, 1 and 2).  Say thread 0 releases the lock and then thread 1 grabs it.  While thread 1 has the lock thread 0 then tries to grab the lock again and when thread 1 releases the lock thread 0 grabs it instead of thread 2.  This could repeat indefinitely and thread 2 never gets the lock.

In this bounding wait algorithm by using the `waiting` array this behavior cannot occur.  If three threads are constantly grabbing the lock the next thread in terms of thread ID will go next, e.g. thread 0 will grab and release the lock followed by thread 1 and then followed by thread 2.  This is because each thread is waiting for either `lock` or its entry in the `waiting` array to become `false`.  If another thread is waiting for the lock when a thread is about to release the lock it sets the `waiting` entry instead of `lock` releasing only that thread from the spin wait.  This prevents the pathological case of one or more threads waiting indefinitely for the lock.

Comment: We might even make it only like this: while (test_and_set(&lock)); right?

Comment: That is how you generally use it, but that would violate the bounded-wait property of this algorithm.

Comment: @Rami I have updated my answer, if there is any confusion please let me know

Comment: Explaining in this level of clarity is an absolute talent @esm! Thank you very much, it is very clear now!

Comment: Hello @missimer, your explanation is awesome .But i have got 1 doubt .As this code should ensure bounded wait and bounded wait says that  "There exists a bound, or limit, on the number of times other processes are allowed to enter their critical sections after a process has made request to enter its critical section and before that request is granted"

Comment: Now by your explanation , i got the point that other thread which were not in CS but Requested to be in CS will get their request by using "else
        waiting[j] = false;
"

Comment: i have doubt that what will happen if j==i , i mean if j==i ,it implies that same process wants to be in CS , then what is the use of " if (j == i) 
        lock = false; " , I guess it will allow  again that proecess(j) to be in CS which will violate Bounded wait.Isn't it?

Comment: @laura,I hope you figured that by now,if not i think it goes as,Consider all of the processes done executing in their critical section and are in their remainder sections,and also note that the first process to execute its critical section has set the lock to true, now we should reset the lock to false so as to other process can go into the Critical section in the next turn or in other words which ever process reaches to the while loop first.