# Bounded Waiting in Test and Set Instruction

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, critical-section

In order to gurantee Bounded wait in  Test and set Instruction,following is the code given in Operating system book,Galvin -:

```
        do {
    1         waiting[i] = true;
    2         while (waiting[i] && test_and_set(&lock)) ;
    3         waiting[i] = false;

    /* critical section */

    4         j = (i + 1) % n;
    5         while ((j != i) && !waiting[j]) 
    6         j = (j + 1) % n; 
    7         if (j == i) 
    8          lock = false; 
    9         else
    10         waiting[j] = false;

    /* remainder section */
         } while (true);
```

I am getting the complete code and concluded that

> A process P_i will be in the critical section if either 
>   Waiting [i]=false or test_and_set(&lock)=FALSE which ensures that Lock was FALSE  previously. so Exit Section is either setting Waiting[j] or lock to FALSE.

But i have got some doubts-:

1. if in the exit section section it is found that same process again  requests for critical section i.e

   ```
       if j==i
   ```

then according to the code,that process have to start its execution form line number 2,i.e will execute

```
       test_and_set(&lock))
```

in while loop and find the return value of test_and_set(&lock)) as false and then move to critical section.My doubt is that if same process wants to be in critical section ,is it necessary to start its exection right from line number 2

2.Now i want to do following Permutation and want to check the possible outcome.i want to swap line number 8 and 10

- in line number 8 if i make

  ```
   waiting[j]=false;
  ```

  then also it will move to critical section even though lock =true now.
- in line number 10 if i make

  lock=false

  then also it(process p_j) will move to critical section even though waiting[i]=true and i think it would be better because line number 3 will assign waiting[i]=false ,after the while loop breaks due to test_and_set(&lock)=false.
  On the other hand if i make this change process have to execute test_and_set(&lock) which is time consuming

Is my assumption for point2 right?

what is the correct reason for point 1?

Thanks

Comment: This code is nonsensical. There must be something other part of it.

Comment: @user3344003  can you please mention the line number ?

Comment: @user3344003 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084724/bounded-waiting-mutual-exclusion-with-test-and-set

Comment: @sourav Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding **point 1**:

> My doubt is that if same process wants to be in critical section ,is
>   it necessary to start its exection right from line number 2

A process is basically an program in execution. A process just cannot jump around choosing which instruction to execute next. The control flow decides that. The control of the code(*which is the process itself*)  suggests that if a process successfully enters **critical section**, and again wants to enter **critical section**, then it will first execute `lines 4 to 10` and then execute **remainder section** and would have to start **execution right from line 1**

Regarding your **point 2**

> Now i want to do following Permutation and want to check the possible
>   outcome.i want to swap line number 8 and 10

If you swap the lines, **the bounded waiting condition** would no longer exist.

**Proof**

Suppose that only 1 process `P(i)` made the request to access **Critical Section** and it successfully entered. So

```
lock = true and waiting[i] = true
```

because only then it would have been able to come out of the for loop. Now it starts executing from `line 4`

Then j takes following values:

```
i + 2 , i + 3, ......0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4....i
```

wrap around of values occurs because of % operator. And Because no other process made request to enter **critical section**, `waiting[j] =  false` for `j != i`

Therefore the condition `while ((j != i) && !waiting[j])` becomes false when `j` equals `i`, and now we are at `line 7`. The new code is:

```
if (j == i) 
  waiting[j] = false;
else
  lock = false;
```

Now if any process makes a request to enter **critical section**, then `while (waiting[i] && test_and_set(&lock)) ;` would always evaluate to `true` because `lock is true` and `waiting[i]` is also `true` and it would be stuck in **spinlock**. There would be no progress.

Comment: @:Summet thank you for your clarification for point 1,but for point 2   you have written  >lock = true and waiting[i] = true  , i agree that lock=true but how wating[i]=true? i am not seeing any line  that makes   "wating[i]=true".

Comment: @sourav waiting[i] = true because of line 1. Any process P(i) that wishes to enter critical section, will have to go through line 1. Its simple as that

Comment: @:Sumeet " Suppose that only 1 process P(i) made the request to access Critical Section and it **successfully entered**. " , i have doubt here that if a process P_i  has successfully entered the CS ,then Waiting[i]=false according to line 3 .?

Comment: What I mean is that, waiting[i] = true when some other process P(I') tries to enter critical section, this I' is different from i. So i am basically talking about a second process that tries to enter critical section (after first process successfully entered and left)when I say waiting[i] is true.